# Young tablaux and its shape: a basic question

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

> Let $D$ and $D'$ be Young tablaux w.r.t. partitions $(n_1\ge  \cdots n_r)$ and $(m_1\ge \cdots \ge m_s)$ of $n$. Suppose that
>
> - If $\alpha,\beta$ are in same row of $D$ then  $\alpha,\beta$ lie in different columns of $D'$.
> - If $\alpha',\beta'$ are in same row of $D'$ then $\alpha',\beta'$ lie in different columns of $D$.

**Question.** Can we conclude that $D$ and $D'$ have same shape (i.e. $n_1=m_1$, $n_2=m_2$, $\cdots$)?

Comment: Yes, we can. Your first assumption shows that the partition $\left(n_1 \geq n_2 \geq \cdots \right)$ dominates the partition $\left(m_1 \geq m_2 \geq \cdots\right)$ (see, for example, Lemma 16 in [Jeremy Booher, *Representations of the symmetric group via Young tableaux*](http://math.arizona.edu/~jeremybooher/expos/young_promys.pdf)), whereas your second assumption shows the opposite relation.